# Ruby: Convert number to short-hand 1K, 2K, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I convert a number like 150000 to something like 150K?

Is it possible to do with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails offers a view helper `number_to_human` that offers all sorts of human-y output

Comment: how can I call this if I'm not using this in a view?

Comment: `require 'action_view';  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper;  number_to_human(1000)`

Comment: Or if you're in the controller just use: `view_context.number_to_human(123412341234)`